# How to cast char without decimal point to decimal in Teradata?

Tags: sql, teradata

I've got a field where data is stored as char(9). The content is numeric and actually a decimal value. Unfornutately the stored value itself doesn't contain a decimal point, only numbers.

I want to store this value inside a decimal(9,2) field. I know that I could use string functions to add a decimal point at the right position, but I'm wondering if there is a nicer way to do this cast. Maybe with TO_NUMBER and the right format string?

Example:

- CHAR(9):  **'000123456'**  -> DECIMAL(9,2):  **1234.56**

Comment: Please add sample table data, showing what the current data is, then also show us the output you want here.

Comment: `col / 100.00`, to avoid possible type cast errors for bad data: `trycast(col as decimal(10,0)) /100.00`

Comment: @dnoeth I'm not sure if this is nicer than using string functions, but it's an alternative that's working. Thanks! Is there a specific reason to use cast to decimal(10,0) instead of (9,0)?

Comment: No, of course (9,0) fits. You need to cast to a numeric anyway, and division by 100 is probably more efficient than two substrings.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid string functions, it might be easier to cast to decimal then divide by 100